# How to disable automatic display selection with a DP monitor

Tags: x11, nvidia, display, plasma, plasma5

So, I have two monitors, a 2160p connected via DP at 0° and a 1080p at 270° connected via HDMI. The 2160p is connected as primary (in KDE System settings) and hence contains the main plasma bar and stuff like that. The other display also contains another plasma toolbar.

The problem is that whenever I switch off the DP monitor, it gets disabled and the other monitor becomes primary. This is what I got in the log:

```
[ 42102.666] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[ 42102.666] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device Samsung U28E590 (DFP-2) (Using EDID frequencies has
[ 42102.666] (**) NVIDIA(0):     been enabled on all display devices.)
[ 42102.669] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung U28E590 (DFP-2): connected
[ 42102.669] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung U28E590 (DFP-2): Internal DisplayPort
[ 42102.669] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung U28E590 (DFP-2): 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[ 42102.669] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[ 42102.684] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "NULL"
[ 42103.605] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select @1080x1920 +3840+0 {ViewPortIn=1080x1920, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0, Rotation=270}"
[ 42103.669] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select @1080x1920 +3840+0 {ViewPortIn=1080x1920, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0, Rotation=270}, DP-0: nvidia-auto-select @1920x2160 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x2160, ViewPortOut=1920x2160+0+0}"
[ 42115.632] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
[ 42115.632] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal DisplayPort
[ 42115.632] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[ 42115.632] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[ 42116.379] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "NULL"
[ 42116.626] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[ 42116.626] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device Samsung U28E590 (DFP-2) (Using EDID frequencies has
[ 42116.626] (**) NVIDIA(0):     been enabled on all display devices.)
[ 42116.628] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung U28E590 (DFP-2): connected
[ 42116.628] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung U28E590 (DFP-2): Internal DisplayPort
[ 42116.628] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung U28E590 (DFP-2): 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[ 42116.628] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[ 42116.636] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "NULL"
[ 42117.451] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select @1080x1920 +3840+0 {ViewPortIn=1080x1920, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0, Rotation=270}"
[ 42117.512] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select @1080x1920 +3840+0 {ViewPortIn=1080x1920, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0, Rotation=270}, DP-0: nvidia-auto-select @3840x2160 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=3840x2160, ViewPortOut=3840x2160+0+0}"
[ 42361.756] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DP-0: nvidia-auto-select @3840x2160 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=3840x2160, ViewPortOut=3840x2160+0+0}"
[ 42373.727] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select @1080x1920 +3840+0 {ViewPortIn=1080x1920, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0, Rotation=270}, DP-0: nvidia-auto-select @3840x2160 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=3840x2160, ViewPortOut=3840x2160+0+0}"
```

The problem is that completely messes up my plasma when the monitor is switched off and I believe this has something to do with DisplayPort, because I used to use 2 monitors earlier on HDMI and never faced this issue (I am inclined to believe that somehow the DP protocol has provision for informing the GPU of the device state).

Is there a way I can ask X to just completely ignore any dynamic configurations and use a static one always (this is a desktop, so I really don't care). This is what my xrandr outputs:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 4920 x 2160, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected 1080x1920+3840+0 right (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 287mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00  
   ~~ snip ~~
DP-0 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 607mm x 345mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+  30.00  
   ~~ snip ~~
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I don't know where it is being initialized from. I use the KDE system settings to configure it, so I believe it is doing so, but I don't know where the config is located. (In KDE4 there used to be this file called krandrcc, which is not present for plasma 5). Also, there is nothing relating to the monitors in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` or in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`. I am using Plasma 5 and Arch Linux.